# Ruby: unique set of digits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, digits

I am a newcomer in Ruby and I need help
I have a sample part of .txt

```
Modified : /Analitics/Documents/HTZ/BR-5545 Credit/Example BR-5545.docx
Modified : /Analitics/Documents/HTZ/BR-5545 Credit/HTZ BR-5545 Example.docx
```

I need to find only digits in rows and only **one time**. (unique set of digits that appears only one time)
With regexp I find digits

```
line=~/(BR-\d*)/
my=line.scan(/(BR-\d*)/)
```

Output:

```
`[["BR-5545"], ["BR-5545"]]`
```

But I need one time:

```
`[["BR-5545"]`
```

Please,help me how to transformate my regexp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an `input.txt` file like this:

```
Modified : /Analitics/Documents/HTZ/BR-5545 Credit/Example BR-5545.docx
Modified : /Analitics/Documents/HTZ/BR-5545 Credit/HTZ BR-5545 Example.docx
```

You could obtain what you want with this

```
File.open('input.txt').inject([]) do |array, line|
  array << line.scan(/(BR-\d*)/)
end.flatten.uniq
```

Basically:

- we open the file
- we start injecting the result of the iteration into the `array` variable, which is initialized to `[]`
- we scan each line for the desired regexp
- after collecting all the results, we flatten it so that we have a one-dimensional array
- then we call uniq on it to remove duplicates

Answer (score 3):

Just add `uniq!` after scanning:

```
data = "Modified : /Analitics/Documents/HTZ/BR-5545 Credit/Example BR-5545.docx"
data.scan(/(BR-\d*)/).uniq! # [["BR-5545"]
```

Comment: Thank you! It's realy help me for rows.Can you give me an advice about colomn of row? I mean now with uniq! I can find a unique in row. But what if I have two rows with the same set of digits? And if these sets are the same I need to exist only one row

Comment: You can use `uniq!` for those as well: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq

Comment: @Priti: it's because he's capturing. It wouldn't be there if the regex was `/BR-\d*/`.

Comment: I am too weak in `Regex`.. Any medicine would you like to prescribe ? :))

Answer (score 2):

Use a Set instead of an array:

```
require 'set'
lines=[
    'Modified : /Analitics/Documents/HTZ/BR-5545 Credit/Example BR-5545.docx',
    'Modified : /Analitics/Documents/HTZ/BR-5545 Credit/HTZ BR-5545 Example.docx'
]

lines.inject(Set.new) {|s, l| s.merge(l.scan(/BR-\d+/)); s}
# => #<Set: {"BR-5545"}>

# or as an array
lines.inject(Set.new) {|s, l| s.merge(l.scan(/BR-\d+/)); s}.to_a
# => ["BR-5545"]
```